# GDB Shared Object unable to get symbols in current context

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries

I have a piece of software that is compiled with several shared libraries. My code is calling a function inside the shared object and crashing inside. I believe my problem is how the parameters are being constructed for this function. I want to validate this by viewing what is happening inside the .so such that I can make the correct changes for how I am constructing the parameters.

The problem I a am running into is not being able to resolve local variables within the shared object. For instance gdb will print out:

```
0x<addr> in <function>(int const* , int, int const*)
```

Based on this I know where I am inside the .so. When I navigate here and try to find what different variables are being set to gdb complains with:

```
No symbol <var> in current context.
```

Now I know for a fact where I am within the code. Additionally, I have checked to make sure the .so was compiled with symbols on and I have also made sure gdb is loading these symbols.

Can anyone inform me on why gdb is unable to see these local variables?

As a note - I haven't used gdb in a while and not to this level of debugging so I am sorry in advance is this is just a limitation of gdb that I am unaware of.

GDB Version: 7.7.1

Edit for comment:

Yes the .so was compile with symbols. I have verified this with:

```
file <.so>
```

This tells me it was dynamically linked and not stripped.

As for commands, I simply trying to print variables.

Overall I am not sure why gdb is unable to resolve the source/exact function of the .so when I explicitly loaded it and made sure the .so was compiled with symbols.

Comment: So the `.so` was compiled with debugging information? Could you give a clearer example with the actual commands you are using and gdb's output?

Answer (score 0):

> I have checked to make sure the .so was compiled with symbols on

*Every* `.so` is compiled with *symbols* on -- it would be useless without symbols.

It's the *debugging info* that you are compiling without. Add `-g` flag to your compile lines, and make sure to not have `-s` or `--strip` anywhere on your link line.

> and I have also made sure gdb is loading these symbols.

Yes, this output `<function>(int const* , int, int const*)` tells us that GDB has read *symbols*, and also that it did *not* load debugging info (these are two completely separate things).